# Delete Duplicate Rows with Multiple columns Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a list of cars, and it will do a lot, the base is not small, about 70k. I want to delete repeated tables, can you tell me how this can be done? For example, if the model and make are repeated, it will delete and leave one.

Use Mysql 5.7.34 version

EXAMPLE:

```
id: 1, model: x5, make: bmw
id: 2, model: x5, make: bmw
id: 3, model: a5, make: audi
id: 3, model: a5, make: audi
```

RESULT:

```
id: 1, model: x5, make:bmw
id: 3, model a5, make: audi
```

I try use this query, but deletes all rows

```
DELETE FROM `car_db` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `carsa` GROUP BY `make`, `model`)
```

Tell me or help me how to make the right request for my task, thanks

Comment: Isn't id unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can delete using a join approach:

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT model, make, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY model, make
) t2
    ON t2.model = t1.model AND
       t2.make  = t1.make  AND
       t2.min_id = t1.id
WHERE
    t2.min_id IS NULL;
```

The above logic will delete, for every group of records belonging to the same model and make, every record which is *not* the minimum `id` record.

Comment: Affected rows: 0, Time: 0.000000s, I try use
```
DELETE t1
FROM car_db3 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT model, make, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM car_db3
    GROUP BY model, make
) t2
    ON t2.model = t1.model AND
       t2.make = t1.make AND
       t2.min_id = t1.id
WHERE
    t2.min_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: but dont delete (

Comment: @Artur Sorry...had a mistake in my logic, please try the updated answer.

Comment: in one table there are rows that are repeated at the top of the example and the result. for example, if there are 2 rows with the same model and make, it will delete and leave one

Comment: Please help me I'm really stuck on this problem

Comment: Try the updated answer, it should work.

Comment: i love you <3, thank you very much!!!!